# Use the result of a JQuery call and use to display an image based on the result name

Tags: jquery, html

I have a script that returns the name of an image file, example "test.png" using a jquery funcation and a call to a data table.

This works great and displays the name of the image in a DIV.

What I am trying to do is use the image file name and display the actual image.

My Jquery is:

```
function get() {
    $.post('check_image.php', {name: form2.CompanyName.value},
        function(output){
            $('#CompanyImage').html(output).show();
        });
}
```

This returns: test.png as text in a DIV.

Is it possible to use test.png and place it on a form img scr like;

```
<img src="test.png" />
```

I have been trying to get this to work using all sorts of methods without success.

Can anyone please help. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: are you tried write like this; $("#CompanyImage').html("<img src=\""+output+"\">"); ?

Comment: Please show response html. `text in a div` doesn't really make much sense for an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this may sound stupid, but do you get name of file or its url? If it's an image url you can use:

```
$("#CompanyImage").html("<img src=\"" + output + "\">");
```

If it's an url not generate url depending on image location. For example if it's in the same folder as your `.html` you can use something like:

```
var url = window.location.href + "/" + output;

$("#CompanyImage").html("<img src=\"" + url + "\">");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<img>', {src: output, alt: ''})
);
```

- create a new `img`-element
- set the `src`- and `alt`-attributes
- append this newly created element to another one in your DOM

**Further Reading**

[jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/27yLbpa4/)